# Java Spark application logs through logger is not showing in EMR log

Tags: java, apache-spark, logging, amazon-emr

I have a Spark java application running on an EMR. When I am trying to run the spark job locally logging into the EMR EC2 instance i am getting my Logger info from the java application on the console.

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.myproject.MyMainSparkClass --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcong.parameters=somepropertiesparameter' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcong.parameters=somepropertiesparameter' --master local s3://myJarS3Location/myjar.jar`

on console my logger info: `19/05/29 01:50:11 INFO DataTransforFileProcessUtility: ############ Job started at :2019-05-29 01:50:11.391 ############`

Where as when i use the cluster mode :

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --class com.myproject.MyMainSparkClass --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcong.parameters=somepropertiesparameter' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcong.parameters=somepropertiesparameter' s3://myJarS3Location/myjar.jar`

I am not able to get the logger info from my application on my console. If i execute the cluster mode command as a step on EMR still i m not finding the application logger info in any of the log files. Does the application logger info gets logged anywhere if we run on cluster mode with Yarn?

Answer (score 0):

When you use cluster mode, you should go to Yarn Resourcemanager  or Spark History Server to get your application log;

In my case(cloudera CDH):
 - Yarn RM:  http:${your_yarn_resourcemanager_host}:8088/cluster 
 - Spark History Server:  http:${your_spark_history_server_host}:18088

Answer (score 0):

When running in Yarn cluster mode, the driver code runs in the same process as that of Application master(AM).
The logs will be logged in AM logs.
You could find the AM from the resource manager, from where you could find the link to logs as well.